# Do I need any MongoDB settings if I am using MongoDB Explorer plugin?

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

If I am using MongoDB Explorer plugin in IntelliJ, do I still need to specify URI in Application Properties file or add a mongoDB dependency?

Comment: You still need to specify URI and something depends on your connection parameters to MongoDB in Application Properties file or add a mongoDB dependency like you mentioned because MongoDB Explorer plugin is a tool to help you manage your dabatase inside IntelliJ, not a part of your application configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much!